# Service Fabric:How to Call Service with ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.UseUniqueServiceUrl?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I'm trying to have a stateless ASP.NET Core service communicate with a stateful ASP.NET core service by using the following configuration on the stateful service:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
        {
            return new ServiceReplicaListener[]
            {
                new ServiceReplicaListener(serviceContext =>
                    new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, (url, listener) =>
                    {
                        ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");

                        return new WebHostBuilder()
                            .UseKestrel()
                            .ConfigureServices(
                                services => services
                                    .AddSingleton<StatefulServiceContext>(serviceContext)
                                    .AddSingleton<IReliableStateManager>(this.StateManager))
                            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                            .UseStartup<Startup>()
                            .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.UseUniqueServiceUrl)
                            .UseUrls(url)
                            .Build();
                    }))
            };
        }
```

I know how to use the reverse proxy by using the following URL `http://localhost:19081/App/Service/api/events?PartitionKey=0&PartitionKind=Int64Range` but I'm confused on how to use it without the reverse proxy. If I try using `fabric:/App/Service` how do I specify the partition? Also, I can't seem to do this with the `HttpClient` class since it only accepts HTTP or HTTPs.

Answer (score 0):

Communicating with a stateful service from within the cluster is usually done by using Service Fabric [Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting). 
It uses a proxy object that handles connections, resolving and retries.

[Here's a sample project](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Dictionary/blob/master/ServiceFabric.Dictionary.IndexService/IndexService.cs#L57) that demonstrates a stateless service talking to a stateful service.
It uses `ServicePartitionKey` to select the right partition, and `TargetReplicaSelector` to select a replica; primary for read/write or secondary for read access.

```
long partitionKey = PartitionAddressFromWord(word);
var proxy = _dictionaryServiceProxyFactory.CreateServiceProxy<IDictionaryService>(DictionaryServiceUri, new ServicePartitionKey(partitionKey), TargetReplicaSelector.PrimaryReplica, DictionaryServiceListenerSettings.RemotingListenerName);
return proxy.Lookup(word);
```

Note that the code to determine the partition key to use is something that you need to create based on the way you have partitioned the service data.
More info [here](https://youtu.be/fN9zQm_FVVw).

Comment: I understand the removing aspect but removing isn't standard communication for all those of services. If I have a container calling a stateful service how would I do that? This was the reason I wanted to do http based communication

Comment: If the container can use the SDK it can use remoting as well. If you want to use HTTP, you can use the built-in DNS service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-dnsservice#using-dns-in-your-services